# Springboot integration with IDP using SAML with a .pem file provided

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-saml

I am new to spring boot. I am doing an integration with spring security  and SAML.
I have

1. IDP metadata.xml
2. Certificate.pem

If there are any references which reflects this requirement please share. It would be really of great help.

Comment: Have you checked out the [Spring Security reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-saml2)?

Answer (score 0):

There are lot many resources in internet available however the one that really helped me to implement the SSO integration using spring boot are

1. [spring-saml2.0-websso-and-jwt-for-mobile-api](https://www.sylvainlemoine.com/2016/06/06/spring-saml2.0-websso-and-jwt-for-mobile-api/)
2. [spring-security-saml2.0-websso-with-angular-client](https://www.sylvainlemoine.com/2018/03/29/spring-security-saml2.0-websso-with-angular-client/)